# Split an array of strings into a 2d array of characters

Tags: python

I am trying to split an array of strings into a 2d array of characters from each string

```
lines = ['abc','123','ggg']
list(lines)
print lines
#['abc','123','ggg']
#nothing changed
#I want [['a','b','c'],['1','2','3'] etc..
```

Whereas with one string,

```
print list('lala')
#['l', 'a', 'l', 'a']
#It works!
```

Thanks

Comment: On a side note: what's the use case for this? You can use strings exactly like lists, do you really need to convert them?

Comment: I think you meant 'print list(lines)'

Answer (score 7):

Using [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> map(list, lines)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['g', 'g', 'g']]
```

Or with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [list(line) for line in lines]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['g', 'g', 'g']]
```

Comment: Simple, concise and to the point (maybe add a note, see my comment on the question)